# Passing URL from WebView to ShareActionProvider?

Tags: android, webview, shareactionprovider

I want to take whatever page the user user is on in my WebView and allow them to share the URL with FaceBook/etc as a ACTION_SEND intent.

I tried this but obviously the URL doesn't exist in the onCreateOptionsMenu. How can I move it to the onOptionsItemsSelected?

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
     mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();
     mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(
       ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
     mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
     return true;   
}
 private Intent createShareIntent() {
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
          web.getUrl());
            return shareIntent;
        }
```

Comment: Just a note, I meant pass it to the onOptionsItemSelected so that "url" will have a value(after the page loads)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code above doesn't work because `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called only once, the first time the options menu is displayed.

Fixing this is quite easy. We're building our Intent when `onOptionsItemSelected` is called. This is when any resource of the inflated menu is selected. If the selected item is the share resource, `shareURL`is executed which now builds and starts the Intent.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            shareURL();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void shareURL() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, web.getUrl());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This!"));
}
```

I didn't test the code sample above. Neither on an actual device nor with the Java compiler. Nevertheless it should help you solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand what your saying, just curious what the undercase intent is? Do I need to create this elsewhere. EDIT: Nevermind it works thanks alot!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. intent -> shareIntent